# How to disable push notifiaction when i logout from application in android

Tags: android

I am using following code on logout button click please have a look :

GCMRegistrar.unregister(mContext);

```
    Intent unregIntent = new Intent(
            "com.google.android.c2dm.intent.UNREGISTER");
    unregIntent.putExtra("app",
            PendingIntent.getBroadcast(mContext, 0, new Intent(), 0));
    unregIntent.putExtra("sender", Data.GCM_REGISTERED_ID);
    mContext.startService(unregIntent);
```

Comment: Use this with Application Context.
GCMRegistrar.unregister(getApplicationContext());
GCMRegistrar.onDestroy(getApplicationContext());

Comment: manish it is mContext==getApplicationContext();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Still i didn't get solution for it but as a quick-fix i have disable notification code forcefully after logout using **boolean flag**..